# C++ Multithreading - algorithm alternative of merge sort with threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, algorithm, sorting

I have written a merge sort algorithm that sort array with integer data.

Now I need to write another sorting algorithm again with multithread concepts -phthread, which again sorting array with integer data.

My task background: 
I have 2 child processes which sorting(with different algorithms) one integer array and first completed task print result and parent kill another process. I had done everything just need to implement 2nd algorithm logic

Please tell me which algorithm I have to use and give me an example implementation

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any divide and conquer algorithm should work.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Requests for free coding services are off-topic. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One portable option is to use [Intel Parallel STL](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/get-started-with-parallel-stl.html). It is compatible with C++11 and implements parallel `std::sort`.

C++17 parallel algorithms in GNU C++ standard library and gcc-9 delegate to Intel Parallel STL.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I was looking for a way that I can implement it i want to learn how to do it(not to use ready function), I am trying to do it right now, I am trying to do it right now using Quicksort, but I am not thinking, that is successful