# What are the implications of suggesting this concurrency library by Microsoft based on Intel's Library?

Tags: c++, concurrency, containers, c++17, libraries

I'm on a Windows platform form with an Intel architecture. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE. I'm in the process of writing a coding example for another question. It pertains to the use of containers, multi-threading, and parallel programming. The Q/A that I'm referring to can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/241635/130733). Before I post anything to make a suggestion or to provide any kind of feedback to the OP, I want to make sure that it is both useful and accurate first.

While I was building my own version or model of their presented application, I had come across some documentation and discovered some header files that Visual Studio is presenting to me through Intellisense or Autocomplete... Here's a list of some of the header files in question:

```
#include <concurrent_priority_queue.h>
#include <concurrent_queue.h>
#include <concurrent_unordered_map.h>
#include <concurrent_unordered_set.h>
#include <concurrent_vector>
#include <internal_concurrent_hash.h>
```

When I was doing more research into these header files, I was getting details on them from Microsoft Docs. However, I have also seen references to Intel's `tbb` library.

After opening one of these files it is giving me this information:

```
/***
* ==++==
*
* Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
* Microsoft would like to acknowledge that this concurrency data structure implementation
* is based on the Intel implementation of its Threading Building Blocks ("Intel Material").
*
* ==--==
* =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
*
* concurrent_vector.h
*
* =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
****/

/*
    Intel Material Copyright 2005-2008 Intel Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.
*/
```

They appear to be Mircosoft's version based on Intel's Concurrency Library model.

Now, if this were Intel's library specifically, I would then assume that it would be portable across the Intel family of architectures agnostic of its operating system... However, with this being Microsoft's version, would this then be Microsoft or platform-specific? Would it be advisable to suggest using this library for concurrency reasons? If not is there another general portable library with similar behavior to serve as a viable replacement?

I don't want to suggest something that may not be useable in their environment. I'm currently at a standstill at this point in the design process to provide a possible useful suggestion. This is where I need more clarity.

Comment: microsoft's concurrency runtime is supported on every platform that MSVC supports.

Comment: @DavidHaim That's is some useful information there... So, if they are on an  AMD, ARM, or RiscV machine running Linux or Mac and don't have MSVC... then it wouldn't be portable for them. So this leads me to think that it is portable in many cases, but not all. So I could suggest it as a viable option if they are targeting those platforms, otherwise suggest a similar alternative library...  However, if one is running Linux on an AMD but is able to have MSVC installed, it is then still portable...

Comment: ummm.. you anyway use MSVC, which only supports Windows, not Mac or Linux. So in conclusion, there is no difference between Microsoft concurrency runtime and  (for example) MSVC std::vector - neither one is "more supported". they are as supported as MSVC supports.

Comment: @DavidHaim Is this from Microsoft Visual Studio or from Microsoft Visual Studio Code? Because Visual Studio Code has ports for some Linux distros and Mac... Visual Studio is now available for Mac, but I didn't see any Linux support that Code has...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Microsoft Visual Studio Code is only an editor, not a compiler. [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) is normally the C/C++ compiler.

Comment: This is Microsoft's [PPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-patterns-library-ppl); it hasn't been updated in years, and MS employees have stated intention to deprecate it in the next VS release or two. Avoid it, move on.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/62120643/412080

Comment: @ildjarn Okay, so what I'm gathering from other commentators is to stay away from the MS version of this library, and should choose Intel's version TBB.

Comment: Yes, if the licensing/potential cost is not an issue for you, TBB is undoubtedly superior from a technical standpoint. That said, it's also a large and opinionated library and often I can get away with just `<atomic>` + Boost.Lockfree. It's impossible to say what someone else "should choose". ;-]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at [Microsoft's Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-patterns-library-ppl?view=vs-2019).

If you care about portability, I would suggest you use [Intel's Threading Building Blocks (TBB)](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB) instead. It is not limited to Intel processors if you are worried about that.